# Getting error when trying to instantiate FileAppender in log4j

Tags: java, apache, logging, log4j

This is the code:

```
PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout("%d{MM-dd-yyyy H:mm:ss.SSS} [%p] (%C{1}.%M) %n    %m");
FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender(patternLayout, fileName);
```

The 2nd line is getting the following error:

```
Error:(40, 37) java: constructor FileAppender in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout<? extends java.io.Serializable>,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager,java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.Advertiser
  found: org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout,java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

However the [log4j javadocs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html) show that a constructor with a PatternLayout as its 1st parameter and a String as the 2nd parameter (for the file name) is a valid constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong import in your class. It should be `import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;`, not `import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender;` or similar.